# New to tikz: create a new coordinate system to use with the Euclide tikz package

Tags: axis, tkz-euclide

I want to draw some descriptive geometry applications using the Euclide Tikz package, but first of all, I need a new X, Y, and Z, coordinate system (see attached picture). The default one offered by Euclide Tikz, does not help me.
Can someone help me with a code for the coordinate system in the attached picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Your sketch can be done easily with plain `Tikz`, which you can combine with `tkz-euclide`, which is built on `Tikz`. Best start with the tutorials in https://tikz.dev/ , with focus on `\draw`, `\node`, `grid`, `circle` and styles. That's all you need for your sketch. // Once you have code to post, I encourage you to add it to your question (when there are problems) or post yourself an answer (which we understand as a solution).

Comment: take a look at `tkz-base` by the same author as `tkz-euclide`

Answer (score 1):

With plain `Tikz`

[image]

For the background

```
        \draw [help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
```

origin at `(-5,-5)`
grid of 5*5

For the axes

```
\draw [<->,line width=2pt, red] %arrow on both sides    
                        (0,-4). %start point for the axis
                            node[right]{$y$} %label on the right side
                                node[left]{$y1$}-- %label on the left side
                        (0,4) %end point for the axis
                            node[left]{$x1$} %label on the left side
                                node[right]{$x1$};%label on the right side
```

For the ticks

```
\foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,3} \draw [line width=2pt, blue](\i,-.1)--(\i,.1);%ticks starting from -3 to 3 horizontal axis
\foreach \z in {-3,-2,...,3} \draw [line width=2pt, blue](-.1, \z)--(.1, \z);%ticks starting from -3 to 3 vertical axis
```

For the intersect at `(-2,3)`

```
\draw [thick, line width=2pt, dashed] (-2,0) |-   (0,3) ;
```

For the circle at the intersection

```
\draw [thick, line width=2pt, dashed] (-2,0) |-   
                node[
                circle,
                fill=black,
                inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt,
                ] {}  
              (0,3) ;
```

For the sloped label at the intersect

```
\draw [thick, line width=2pt, dashed] (-2,0) |-   
                node[
                circle,
                fill=black,
                inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt,
                label={
                    [label distance=0.2cm,
                        rotate=45]
                        above:(-2,3)}] {}  
              (0,3) ;
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}


\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,]
            \draw [help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

            \draw [<->,line width=2pt, red]         
                            (0,-4)
                                node[right]{$y$} 
                                    node[left]{$y1$}--
                            (0,4) 
                                node[left]{$x1$} 
                                    node[right]{$x1$};
            \draw [<->, line width=2pt, red]    
                            (-4,0)
                                node[above]{$y$} 
                                    node[below]{$y1$}--
                            (4,0) 
                                node[above]{$x$}
                                    node[below]{$x1$};
          \foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,3} \draw [line width=2pt, blue](\i,-.1)--(\i,.1);
                  \foreach \z in {-3,-2,...,3} \draw [line width=2pt, blue](-.1, \z)--(.1, \z);
                  
                  \draw [thick, line width=2pt, dashed] (-2,0) |-   
                    node[
                    circle,
                    fill=black,
                    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt,
                    label={
                        [label distance=0.2cm,
                            rotate=45]
                            above:(-2,3)}] {}  
                  (0,3) ;

        \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```